# Dialog not does not pop out (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The View.xhtml file has:

```
<p:column>
                            <p:commandButton value="View Returns" ajax="true" immediate="false" oncomplete="dlg3.show()"
                                             update=":bookingForm:tabView:returnsDialog" process="itemDetailTable">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tripdebriefdetailController.ordrDetail}"
                                                             value="#{item}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
```

and

```
<p:dialog id="returnsDialog" header="Capture Ruturns" widgetVar="dlg3" resizable="false"
                              dynamic="true">
                        <p:dataTable value="#{tripdebriefdetailController.tripOrdrDetailDebriefList}"
                                     paginatorPosition="bottom" var="item" rowKey="#{item.id}" paginator="true"
                                     rows="10" id="itemTableDebriefDetail">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <div style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 14px;">
                                    #{bundle.ListTripdebriefdetailTitle}
                                </div>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:column headerText="#{bundle.ListTripdebriefdetailTitle_qty}" sortBy="#{item.qty}">
                                #{item.qty}
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{bundle.ListTripdebriefdetailTitle_returnDate}"
                                      sortBy="#{item.returnDate}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.returnDate}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{bundle.ListTripdebriefdetailTitle_returnType}"
                                      sortBy="#{item.returnType}">
                                #{item.returnType}
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{bundle.ListTripdebriefdetailTitle_returnReason}"
                                      sortBy="#{item.returnReason}">
                                #{item.returnReason}
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:dialog>
```

The dialog does not work. I don't know what is wrong hear. I need some assistance on this.

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using? For what I can see dlg3.show() was used in the earlier versions of PF but has since been replaced due to some issues. Later versions now do it like this: PF('dlg3').show()

Answer (score 2):

if you use primefaces 3.5 or above;

you should use in button
   **onclick="PF('dlg3').show()"**

Comment: I used oncomplete="PF('dlg3').show()" . It worked. Thanks